# TTS to audio (mp3) using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012

i have developed a small application in c# using vs2013 which converts Text to Speech however i want to save that speech automatically in a database as an audio file (.mp3 or any other web supported format). is it possible? how it can be implemented, a code snippet shall be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to upload the audio file to any directory in your server, and only store the url adress in your Database as a `String`. You can simply use the `FileUpload` control.

This is an article which i think can help you. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667306/Upload-an-Image-and-an-Audio-file-using-Csharp

Goodluck.

Comment: thanks however my question has 2 parts, 1. how to save in mp3 format and second how to save in sql. your answer support 2nd part.